# Make a request with API Fetch using IPv6 in NodeJS 18

Tags: node.js, debian, ipv6

I have a Debian server with IPv4 and IPv6 and every time I make a request from the NodeJS Fetch API it is **done using IPv4**.

I understand that the server is prioritizing the network with the IPv4, but is there a way to change this preference only in NodeJS? And **force** it to make the Fetch requests from IPv6?